# org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Nutch custom plugin not found exception in deploy mode

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

I have a working custom index filter plugin for nutch 1.12. It is working in local mode(standalone). When i run nutch in deploy mode,the following exception.

```
`Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.indexfilter.CustomIndexFilter
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.getOrderedPlugins(PluginRepository.java:469)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilters.<init>(IndexingFilters.java:43)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.configure(IndexerMapReduce.java:94)
    ... 22 more`
```

Comment: Are you bundling the custom plugin in the job file?

Comment: @JorgeLuis Now i am creating plugin in source directory and building using ant command

Comment: Could you decompress the `.job` file and check if your plugin is in there? If you're building Nutch with `ant` it should be there and bundled along with the default plugins.